# How to automatically display horizontal scroll bar in panel when minimized form?

Tags: c#, winforms, scroll, panel

I have a groupbox to display my config items. The groupbox is in a panel in a form.

When the form loads, it opens on maximized mode. During this time, the vertical scrollbar in panel is displayed which is correct. The horizontal scrollbar at this time not displayed because i can still see all the text which is correct.

But when i minimized the form that is where the problem is. I cannot see the whole text of config items and i cannot scroll to the right to read it because there is no horizontal scrollbar. Is there a way to solve this? Or is there a way to always enable horizontal scrollbar at all time? Please help. Thank you.

```
        // 
        // panel1
        // 
        this.panel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.panel1.AutoScroll = true;
        this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.grpBoxConfItems);
        this.panel1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1164, 224);
        this.panel1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(6, 6, 6, 6);
        this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
        this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(682, 810);
        this.panel1.TabIndex = 4;
        // 
        // grpBoxConfItems
        // 
        this.grpBoxConfItems.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
        | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
        this.grpBoxConfItems.AutoSize = true;
        this.grpBoxConfItems.Controls.Add(this.lblValue);
        this.grpBoxConfItems.Controls.Add(this.lblKey);
        this.grpBoxConfItems.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
        this.grpBoxConfItems.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(34, 32);
        this.grpBoxConfItems.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(6, 6, 6, 6);
        this.grpBoxConfItems.Name = "grpBoxConfItems";
        this.grpBoxConfItems.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(6, 6, 6, 6);
        this.grpBoxConfItems.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(712, 744);
        this.grpBoxConfItems.TabIndex = 0;
        this.grpBoxConfItems.TabStop = false;
        this.grpBoxConfItems.Text = "Configuration Items";
```

**UPDATE**
So i have decided to make the scrolls always visible whether in maximized or minimized mode.

```
                this.panel1.Anchor = ((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles)(((System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Top | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Left) 
                | System.Windows.Forms.AnchorStyles.Right)));
                this.panel1.AutoScroll = false;
                this.panel1.VerticalScroll.Visible = true;
                this.panel1.VerticalScroll.Enabled = true;
                this.panel1.HorizontalScroll.Visible = true;
                this.panel1.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = true;
                this.panel1.Controls.Add(this.grpBoxConfItems);
                this.panel1.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Microsoft Sans Serif", 11.25F, System.Drawing.FontStyle.Bold, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point, ((byte)(0)));
                this.panel1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(1164, 224);
                this.panel1.Margin = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(6, 6, 6, 6);
                this.panel1.Name = "panel1";
                this.panel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(682, 810);
                this.panel1.TabIndex = 4;
```

The scrolls are both showing but they are not functioning. And when i set `this.panel1.AutoScroll = true;` after `this.panel1.HorizontalScroll.Enabled = true;` the vertical scroll is functioning but horizontal scroll is missing. Please help me how can i solve this? Thank you.

Comment: Why do your keep your `panel1` anchored `{Left, Top, Right }`? It will shrink to nothing if you resize the Form. It should be docked to the right.

Comment: @Jimi This is an old system in company. And i am new here. So i am not sure why they do what they do. But thank you for pointing that out. When i set it to top left. It works now. Thank you so much!